# Is there any priority queue with O(1) insertion and removal when the elements are added in ascending order?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

It is not possible to make a priority queue with `O(1)` insertion and removal. After all, if it was possible, then one could sort a list in `O(N)`. But, suppose that the elements are added in ascending order - that is, in a particular use instance, the last element added is always the first element to be removed. Then, is there a priority queue that will behave with constant lookup/removal for that use?

Note: I am **not** asking for a stack. I'm asking for a priority queue that degenerates to constant lookup/removals under this specific usage pattern - similar to sorting algorithms that degenerate to O(N) best case for almost-sorted lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use a linked list sorted in descending priority order.

For removing an element, just remove the first element. This is always O(1).

For adding an element:

- If the list is empty, simply insert the element.
- Otherwise, walk the list until a lower-priority element is found. Insert the new element before the lower-priority element.

This is O(1) in the case that the new element is the highest priority. This algorithm will check the first element, and either find it to not exist (in the case of the empty list) or be a lower priority than the new element.

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly nothing stopping you from *implementing* such a beast.

For example, when you add an element to your currently empty collection, or when the items are still coming in in increasing order, you simply add the item to a *stack.*

However, if at any point you add an item with priority *less* than the previous one, simply move all the stack entries across to an empty queue (in all mentions of queue below, I mean priority queue) under the covers, before finally adding your new item to that queue.

Once you empty out the queue, you will again revert to the stack as default.

So, basically, the pseudo-code would be something like this. First, the instance variables:

```
class uberqueue:
    lastPrio = 0
    stack = []
    prioq = []
```

Then the `put` function which performs the actions specified above:

```
    def put (item):
        # Empty, use stack.

        if stack.size() == 0 and prioq.size() == 0:
            stack.push(item)
            lastPrio = item.prio
            return

        # Stacking and in order, add to stack.

        if stack.size() > 0 and item.prio >= lastPrio:
            stack.push(item)
            lastPrio = item.prio
            return

        # Stacking and out of order, transfer stack to queue.

        while stack.size() > 0:
            prioq.put(stock.pop())

        # Queueing, add to queue.

        prioq.put(item)
```

And, finally, the `get` function which just gets an item from the currently active underlying structure (stack or queue):

```
    def get():
        # Just get from whatever underlying structure is in use.

        if stack.size() > 0:
            return stack.pop()

        return prioq.get()
```

And, there you have it, a data structure that gives you O(1) insert/retrieve performance if you follow the priority sequencing guidelines, but reverts to priority queue performance otherwise.

---

And, in fact, you could probably even get rid of the stack-to-queue transfer totally if both stack and queue offered the ability to peek at the next item priority.

A way of doing that would be to place items into the stack when their priority was greater than or equal to that of the top element. That ensures all items in the stack are ordered correctly. All out-of-order items go straight into the priority queue.

The `get` functionality then has to change slightly, peeking at the stack and queue to see which has the highest priority, and extracting that one.

It's a bit trickier but may offer advantages in some circumstances.